# sending mail to multiple users through asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, email, gmail

I want to modify this method to allow sending mail to multiple users instead of one by one .

I use the following method to send mail to bulk of users through putting the method in a loop according to the number of users but it takes several minutes making the user feeling that something wrong has been happened ..

```
public static string sendMail(string to, string title, string subject, string body)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                if (to == "")
                    to = "----@gmail.com";
                MailAddressCollection m = new MailAddressCollection();
                m.Add(to);
                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.From = new MailAddress( "----@gmail");
                mail.Body = body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.ReplyTo = new MailAddress("----@gmail");
                mail.To.Add(m[0]);
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                 client.Port = 25;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("----@gmail", "####");
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; }; 

                smtp.Send(mail);

                return "done";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Is there some way to refactor this method to allow sending the mail to multiple user .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static string sendMail(string[] tolist, string title, string subject, string body)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                if (to == "")
                    to = "----@gmail.com";
                MailAddressCollection m = new MailAddressCollection();

                //Add this
                foreach(string to in tolist)
                {
                    m.Add(to);
                }
                //
                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.From = new MailAddress( "----@gmail");
                mail.Body = body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.ReplyTo = new MailAddress("----@gmail");

                //And Add this 
                foreach(MailAddress ma in m)
                {
                    mail.To.Add(ma);
                }
                //or maybe just mail.To=m; 


                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                 client.Port = 25;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("----@gmail", "####");
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; }; 

                smtp.Send(mail);

                return "done";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: @just_name Say you want to send email to 10 addresses, I believe you initial way will call `sendMail` 10 times, now it will call it only once.

Comment: i will send to about 500 address

Comment: @just_name so you definitely need to change your code to something like I've provided above.